# Create a new column using computed values in query set in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I am working on top of an existing project, I am not allowed to make migrations to the current model. Suppose  I have a model like this:

`class Things(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)`

`objs = Things.objects.values('name')`
will give me the following result

`|objs| 
|----|
|apple|
|orange|
|banana|
|fruits|
|car|
|bus|
|motorcycle|
|autombiles|`

so if i do : somequery = objs.some_function(), how do i get the following result, assuming its possible.

`|cats       |  objs    |
|------------------    |
|automobiles|car       |
|automobiles|bus       |
|automobiles|motorcycle|
|fruits     |apple     |
|fruits     |orange    |
|fruits     |banana    |
-------------------------`

from what I read about this so far, there isn't a straightforward way of solving this without altering the models.py. Any help/suggestion will help me tremendously.

Comment: How do you find out categories to differentiate obj type from CharField? I am not able to find out car obj as automobiles category, or apple obj as fruits category from name field.

Comment: What I have in the second table is the end result, I want to see.Yup, I do not have an existing column with 'cats' type. I only have a limited number of objs. So, I can filter them by name , if objs =='car' or 'bus' or 'motorcycle' then cat = automobiles. But is it possible though, in Django if so, how? For eg., in pandas , I could do df['new_col'] = df.some_computation(). Is that a possibility here.